# Cypress installation through NPM doesn't work

Tags: node-modules, npm-install

I give the command `npm rum cypress install` or `npx cypress install` but the installation never finishes. It looks like something is blocking the installation but I have no idea what it is. Could anyone help me with this problem?

code error below:

```
$ npm run cypress install

> projetosweb@1.0.0 cypress
> cypress install

Installing Cypress (version: 12.9.0)
```

I ran the command `npm run cypress verify` to check if I was missing something, but it didn't find the version installed in C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\12.9.0\Cypress

So I gave the command `npm run cypress install` but the installation never finished.

I also tried to issue the command `npm install cypress --save-dev` but after installing and executing the command `npx cypress open` an error appears:

No version of Cypress is installed in: C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\12.9.0\Cypress

Versions I'm using:

```
$ npm --version
9.5.0

$ node --version
v18.15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this,
Write first, `npm init -y`
and then write `npm install cypress`
then, `npm cypress -v`
finally, `npx cypress verify`

for opening cypress `npx cypress open`

1.

[image: cypress installation picture]

2.
[image]

I hope this will work.